# What's a good C decompiler?

Tags: c, linux, reverse-engineering, decompiling, assembly

I am searching for a decompiler for a C program. The binary is a 32-bit x86 Linux executable. Objdump works fine, so basically I am searching for something which attempts to reconstruct the C source from the asm source.

Comment: maybe better ask on the below sites? http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There are none.  No decompiler is good, by definition of the process.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Seconding Hex-rays, but if you can't justify that cost, [Boomerang](http://boomerang.sourceforge.net/) might work.

Comment: I tested it with some windows binaries, and Boomerang just decompiled a small one. The others crashed this decompiler.

Comment: Hell of a libqt dependencies, not just core and gui, but also dev. Consider this.

Comment: @CodyBrocious : He asked for Linux programs.

Comment: But notice that boomerang doesn't decompile AMD x86_64 binary....

Answer (score 19):

If you have money to spare, [Hex-Rays Decompiler](http://www.hex-rays.com/decompiler.shtml) could be worth your while. :-)

Comment: Any ideas for [this case](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/26830/2341) ?

Comment: Hopper license is a fraction of  cost cheaper, and pretty much does a good/comparable job.

Answer (score 11):

As much as IDA can be helpful it cost quite a lot of money.
Not sure about your specific use case but [Plasma](https://github.com/plasma-disassembler/plasma) seems like it would do the trick "Plasma is an interactive disassembler for x86/ARM/MIPS. It can generate indented pseudo-code with colored syntax."

If you are looking for something more similar to IDA I heavily recommend [Radare2](https://github.com/radare/radare2). There's also [ODA the online dissembler](https://onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/) in case you don't feel like installing anything.

A new addition is [Binary Ninja](https://binary.ninja/) and although it's not even close to the capabilities of IDA or Radare yet, it's a cheap and good utility for starters.

Update:
Since this comment the NSA have released [Ghidra](https://ghidra-sre.org/) which is completely open source and free. It is a full pledges RE framework with high end decompiler.

Answer (score 9):

For binary decompiling, I have bought a personal license of Hopper https://www.hopperapp.com .

The advantages are:

- has an intuitive and well thought graphical interface;
- runs in MacOS and Linux;
- provides a reasonable C-like decompiler output;
- decompiles 32-bit **and** 64-bit binaries;
- supports Mach-O binaries (Mac and iOS), PE32/32+/64 Windows binaries and ELF binaries;
- has very regular free updates;
- the license price at around 100 USD cannot be beaten.

IMO, the ratio cost/quality beats fairly easily IDA/Hex-rays, and it leaves in the dust the other commercial (or free) decompilers.

Additionally, you can try it out or use the demo version to get a feel of it and decompile (very) small executables for free.

[image: Hopper]

From now on (March/2019), as an alternative, you also have [Ghidra](https://ghidra-sre.org) from NSA. Ghidra runs on Linux, Mac and Windows as long as JDK 11 is installed. It is presented "as a free tool comparable to X/Rays".

[image: Ghidra]

Ghidra feels more powerful, however Hopper still seems more intuitive.

See also: [PepperMalware Blog - Quick Analysis of a Trickbot Sample with NSA's Ghidra SRE Framework](http://www.peppermalware.com/2019/03/quick-analysis-of-trickbot-sample-with.html)

Answer (score 3):

Snowman (http://derevenets.com) looks nice. The generated code is a mess, but works.