# Decompiling x86 PE binary to C?

Tags: decompiler, disassembly, ollydbg

I'd like to know if there's any way to generate the C code of a x86 PE binary. I don't really *need* this, I just want to learn how some closed-source software are working.

From my common sense, I think the process is:

- Converting the x86 binary to Assembly, which can be done with a disassembler like OllyDbg.
- Converting this Assembly to C. I don't know any tools for that, any that's my question actually.

Comment: The legality of this depends a lot on what exactly you want to do, where you live and what license/contract you signed when you got the exe. In some places reverse-engineering for interoperability is legal, in others reverse-engineering is never legal (no, I'm not a Lawyer).

Comment: It's hard to reverse assembly to HLL, especially after compiler optimisations. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193896/whats-a-good-c-decompiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use IDA Pro with the HexRay decompiler you can get a somewhat readable C source code. (But prepare for a bunch of `goto`-s and unnecessary variables).