# C Library inspector (reflector-like)?

Tags: c, windows, reflector

Is there a reflector of any kind for C libraries?

I'm looking for a program that is able to tell what's in a given C library(ies).

Comment: Nothing that's as effective as reflector, certainly.

Comment: Are you looking for the exported functions (all of the things you can access if you had the appropriate headers and link strategy) or a disassembly (to see all of the code)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193896/whats-a-good-c-decompiler

Comment: @Petruza - disassembler/decompiler

Comment: Do you know what reflector is? I want such a tool for C DLLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think IDA tools can help you, there is freeware version that can be download from here:

[IDA Pro 5.0 Freeware Version](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/idadownfreeware.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [dumpbin utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) under windows to get the export symbols. I'm pretty sure there is something similar for linux libraries. Not as good as reflector but at least gives you an idea of what's there.

**Update**: The Linux equivalent seems to be [nm](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_nm.htm)