# Is it possible to get an intermediate, optimized C file using GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, optimization

I have some C code with a loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<1000; i+=ceil(sqrt(i)))
{
    do stuff that could benefit from loop unrolling;
}
```

I intend on using a macro command to tell GCC to unroll the loops, but I'd like to make sure it will indeed unroll the loop in this case (since the increment is not 1, but it could still be preprocessed and unrolled).

Is it possible to get GCC to output a .C file containing the code after it's been optimized? (Hopefully including any optimization it does with `-O` that come before the assembly-level optimizations)?

I know I can confirm this using the assembly output, but I'd rather see something in C - much easier for me to read and understand.

Comment: In GCC, optimization does not happen until after the code is no longer recognizable as C, so this is probably not doable. If you learn to read the intermediate code, though, you can tell GCC to save the temporary files at various stages...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C is a high-level, compiled language.  Therefore, it is not an appropriate representation of the optimized machine code.  Although, you might feel like seeing C code will be easier to understand, it lacks the absolute precision of the assembly, which maps directly to machine code.  For this simple example, you might have a pretty good idea what optimization means in terms of a high-level language, but this is not the case in general with optimizations.  Viewing the assembly language shows exactly what the compiler has done.

Secondly, compilers perform optimizations on some sort of [intermediate representation (IR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_language), which is more similar to machine code than high-level code (C in this case).  To output high-level code after performing optimizations would require a decompilation step.  GCC is not the appropriate place to add decompilation logic for a rarely used feature like this.  But, if you *really* want to see the optimized code in C, you could run the assembly produced by GCC through a decompiler to get high-level code back.

Short answer: GCC will not do what you want, but you can produce C code from assembly with a decompiler.

[Here is a stack overflow thread about choosing a good C decompiler for linux.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193896/whats-a-good-c-decompiler)

Comment: Thank you (and twalberg). I never studied compilers in-depth enough  to know the specifics.